# Firebase Authentication for MOODLE

Tags: firebase-authentication, moodle

I have created a Moodle portal. Is it possible to have FIREBASE authentication (for Sign-Up and Sign-In) for MOODLE?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default provider for Moodle sign-in for Firebase, but you can [create your own custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) that mints Firebase tokens based on your verified Moodle credentials.

The flow for this is:

1. You collect the user's credentials and pass these to your server.
2. You call the Moodle API to sign the user in.
3. You then mint a Firebase token from the verified information about this user.
4. You pass the token back to the client, and sign in to Firebase there.